# How to extract/export html data in angular in HTML format

Tags: javascript, html, angular, copy

I have an application, that accumulate data from server in HTML page. In early version I used JSP + JS and my follow function have been used to copy generated html-data to clipboard (after that user can copy clear HTML and paste it to Mozila Thunderbird program):

```
function getHtml() {

    var $div = $('#fullRezult'); 
    var y = $div.html(); 
    $("#myModal2").modal('show'); 
    $('#paste').val(y);

}
```

But now I use Angular 6 and my content is generating by construction like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered  table-sm">
            <tbody>
            <tr [ngClass]="{'green': el.id == 1}" *ngFor="let el of childElements">
                <td>{{el.id}}</td>
                <td>{{el.name}}</td>
                <td>{{el.description}}</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-success">Success</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

So, **how I can copy clear pure html of generated table to some textarea field in angular 6???**

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use **ViewEncapsulation**. Create example component

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-mycomponent',
    template: `<div class="mycomponent"><h1>It's my component!</h1><p *ngIf="!!variable">{{variable}}</p></div>`,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MycomponentComponent implements OnInit {

    variable: 123;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

and then in parent component View create button to get HTML code

```
<button
    type="button"
    (click)="getHTML()">Get HTML</button>
```

finally in parent component write method to get HTML from DOM element using this code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(
    private el: ElementRef
)

getHTML() {

    return this.el.nativeElement
               .querySelector('.mycomponent')
               .outerHTML
               .replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to target and grab the outer html of the element whose HTML you want to capture.

The following is one way to do this:

```
function getElementOuterHTML(element) {
    if (typeof element === 'undefined' || element==null) {
        return '';
    }
    if(!element || !element.tagName) return '';
    if(element.outerHTML) return element.outerHTML;
    try {
        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
        return wrapper.innerHTML;
    } catch (e) { return ''; }
}

function getHtml() {
    var tableNodes = document.querySelectorAll('table');
    if (tableNodes.length>0) {
        tableNodes.forEach(function(){
            console.log(getElementOuterHTML(this));
        });
    }
}
```

Or, specifically your code could be:

```
function getHtml() {

    var $div = $('#fullRezult'); 
    var y = getElementOuterHTML($div[0]); 
    $("#myModal2").modal('show'); 
    $('#paste').val(y);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here i am try save my table data as pdf and excel by adding some export headers and searching filter texts.

Export as Excel

```
exportToExcel(): void {
    const customLines = [
      ['Search Filter'],
      ['Date', this.endDate],
      ['Search Text', this.SearchText],
      ['Balance > ', this.balance]
    ];


    const headers = ['Sr. No.', 'Name', 'Balance', 'Amount'];
    const excelData = [
      ...customLines,
      headers,
      ...this.invoiceList.map((item, index) => [
        index + 1,
        `${item.LedgerName} - ${item.Place}`,
        item.Balance,
        item.Amount
      ])
    ];

    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(excelData);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, 'PaymentWiseList');
  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    const url: string = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const a: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName + '.xlsx';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
```

Export as Pdf

```
exportPdf(data: any[], pdf: string) {

    const customLines = [
      ['Search Filter'],
      ['Date', this.endDate],
      ['Search Text', this.SearchText],
      ['Balance > ', this.balance]
    ];

    const documentDefinition = {
      content: [
        {
          table: {
            ...customLines,
            headerRows: 1,
            widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
            body: [
              ['Name', 'Balance', 'Amount'],
              ...data.map(item => [

                item.Name + '-' + item.Place || '-',
                item.Balance || '-',
                item.Amount || '-'
              ])
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      layout: {
        defaultBorder: false
      }
    };

    try {
      pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition, null, null, pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs).download('Report.' + pdf);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error generating PDF:', error);
    }

  }
```